# Correct latin-1 encoded UTF-8 in Django-ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I'm setting up a django-admin on top of a legacy MySQL database.

The database declares that it is latin-1 encoded. Some of the entered data in the database is indeed in latin-1 but some is actually UTF-8. This shows up as corrupt characters like: Ã© â‚¬ Ã¤ Ã¶

The legacy application does some black magic to hide these errors and I cannot modify the database.

I found a Python library `ftfy` that can convert latin-1 corrupted UTF-8 to real UTF-8, for example the above chars get translated to "é € ä ö". I want to use it on all `django.db.models.CharField` and `django.db.models.TextField` data that is loaded from database. How to do it?

I tried to subclass `django.db.models.CharField` and `django.db.models.TextField` but couldn't figure out where to intercept the data from database. Optimal solution would be something like `FTFYCharField` which would always correct data that it gets from database.

Comment: It depends on if you want to "correct" the data as it goes into the DB, or "corrupt" it on the way into DB, and then "fix" it on the way out.

Comment: I want to 'fix' data that is being read from the database.

Comment: What about what (if anything) is being written to *to* the DB? Or is this read-only from the Django site's point of view?

Comment: I'm happy with read-only for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming read-only, I think what you are looking for is [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/). In particular, look at the section [Converting database values to Python objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-database-values-to-python-objects). In the `.to_python()` method you can do what ever you want to any/all fields read from the DB.

If you also need to write (and maintain the weirdness), see the section on [Preprocessing values before saving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#preprocessing-values-before-saving).

Comment: I was missing `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase` from my `FTFYCharField`. `.to_python()` doesn't seem get called without it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are times when the `to_python` method might be called multiple times. For this use it ought to be safe though as I'm sure the conversion is idempotent.

Comment: @KayEss: Didn't know that about `.to_python()`. Do you have a link?

Comment: @PeterRowell, no link, just from personal experience writing a few custom fields.

Comment: @KayEss: Good to know about. It's the kind of thing that can bite you in the ass and then you go crazy trying to figure out what it was.

Comment: I remember where it was now. In here I have to sniff the type being passed in to see if it's already been converted or not https://github.com/KayEss/django-slumber/blob/master/slumber/fields.py You'll see that the conversions to the database type need the same handling

Answer (score 1):

I know that this might be OFF...
but maybe prevents some headache

before you make any "unicode" related change then please get to know what unicode means, and note that what you wrote "Ã¶" == ö is only right when the unicode is encoded by the method UTF-8